# Haskell: Couldn't match type [Int] with Int

Tags: haskell

Hi here is my code below.

```
data Treeof a = Node Int a [Treeof a]  deriving (Eq,Show)

add_score :: Int -> Treeof a -> [[Int]]
add_score 0 (Node i a xs) = [[0]]
add_score n (Node i a xs) = [i]:[(map (add_score (n-1)) xs)]
```

I trying to obtain the Int stored in each Node of a Tree and store it in a list of lists but get the error shown below and I'm unsure why.

```
    Couldn't match type `[[Int]]' with `Int'
    Expected type: Treeof a -> Int
      Actual type: Treeof a -> [[Int]]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(add_score (n - 1))'
    In the expression: (map (add_score (n - 1)) xs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

EDIT: Changed [i]:[(map (add_score (n-1)) xs)] to [i]:(map (add_score (n-1)) xs)

And getting a similar error

```
    Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Int'
    Expected type: Treeof a -> [Int]
      Actual type: Treeof a -> [[Int]]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(add_score (n - 1))'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely
      `(map (add_score (n - 1)) xs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here - you don't add anything!

Comment: @Carsten I'm trying get the Ints stored in Nodes of a Tree and add each score up for each branch of the first level of the tree after the initial node.

Comment: Please paste a code snippet rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xs` has type `[TreeOf a]`. Clearly, you *can* map `add_score (n-1)` over such a list as you did, since this takes `TreeOf a` as an argument.

But what's the result? Well, a list of whatever the result of a single `add_score (n-1)` is. But that's already a `[[Int]]`, so you get

```
map (add_score $ n-1) xs :: [ [[Int]] ]
```

which is one nesting level too much. Now wrapping this in another singleton list is clearly counterproductive. On the contrary, you need to *flatten* one list level. There are at least three ways to do this:

- Concatenate the outer lists.

  ```
     [i] : (concat $ map (add_score $ n-1) xs)
  ```

  this can be more nicely written with `=<<` (aka `concatMap`), as

  ```
     [i] : (add_score (n-1) =<< xs)
  ```
- Concatenate the *inner* lists.

  ```
     [i] : (map (concat . add_score (n-1)) xs)
  ```
- Sum up the innermost list.

  ```
     [i] : (map (map sum . add_score (n-1)) xs)
  ```

You must know yourself which behaviour you want; the first seems most useful to me.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The error is simply telling you there is one too many (or one too few) layers of lists somewhere.

Why are you putting `map ...` as a single element of a list:

```
[(map (add_score (n-1)) xs)]
```

At first blush, it appears you want:

```
(map (add_score (n-1)) xs)
```

But then since `add_source` fully applied yields a `[[Int]]`, mapping it will be of type `[[[Int]]]` (thanks @Carsten).  You might be after:

```
concatMap (add_score (n-1)) xs
```

That will concatenate the list and yield a result of type `[[Int]]`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!